# Variable does not exist: insert record

Tags: apex, apex-variable

I'm trying to insert a new record into an object where I pull information from `OpportunityLineItem`, `Product`, `Opportunity`, and `Account`. I did a query and get the results I want. Then I go to create a new record with the results of the query and I get the error:

> Variable does not exist: `oli.Opportunity.AccountId`

`oli` is the name I used in the for loop to search for `OpportunityLineItem` records, what am I doing wrong? In other variable does not exist posts it references when you create a variable and then in a different method try and reference that variable again. This is all in the same method so I am confused.

Example:

```
public with sharing class RevenuePipelineHandler {
    public static void createRevPipeline(Set<Id> oppyIds) {
        List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> revPipeline = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();

        for(OpportunityLineItem oli:[SELECT Start_Date__c, 
                                            End_Date__c,
                                            TotalPrice,
                                            Is_Fund__c,
                                            OpportunityId,
                                            Opportunity.AccountId,
                                            Opportunity.Account.Account_BU_2__c,
                                            Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode,
                                            Opportunity.Practice__c,
                                            Opportunity.Cash_or_Barter__c,
                                            Opportunity.StageName,
                                            Opportunity.Sales_Order_Approved_Date__c,
                                            Product2Id,
                                            Product2.ALR_Retailer__c,
                                            Product2.Product_LOB__c,
                                            Product2.Product_Type__c,
                                            Product2.Family,
                                            Product2.Product_Group__c,
                                            Product2.Product_Offering__c
                                            FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppyIds])

        {
            revPipeline.add(new Revenue_Pipeline__c(
                Account__c = oli.Opportunity.AccountId,
                ALR_Retailer__c = oli.Product2.ALR_Retailer__c,
                Cash_Barter__c = oli.Opportunity.Cash_or_Barter__c,
                Cross_Practice__c = oli.Opportunity.Account.Account_BU_2__c,
                CurrencyIsoCode = oli.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode,
                External_Id__c = oli.Product2.Family + '/' + oli.Product2.Product_Group__c + '/' + oli.Product2.Product_Offering__c,
                Is_Fund__c = oli.Is_Fund__c,
                Name = oli.OpportunityId + '-' + oli.Product2Id,
                Opportunity__c = oli.OpportunityId,
                Practice__c = oli.Opportunity.Practice__c,
                Product_AU__c = oli.Product2.Product_LOB__c,
                Product_End_Date__c = oli.End_Date__c,
                Product_Price__c = oli.TotalPrice,
                Product_Start_Date__c = oli.Start_Date__c,
                Product__c = oli.Product2Id,
                Revenue_Type__c = 'DANDAN',
                Subscription_Type__c = oli.Product2.Product_Type__c));
        }
        insert revPipeline;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with help from this post: [Compile Error: Variable does not exist: o.CloseDate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113476/compile-error-variable-does-not-exist-o-closedate)

I had a newline/line break between the line between FROM and {:

```
FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppyIds])

    {
        revPipeline.add(new Revenue_Pipeline__c(
```

The correct code is:

```
    FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppyIds])
    {
        revPipeline.add(new Revenue_Pipeline__c(
```

So if only the first line is considered in the loop and there is a blank space then the rest is out of the loop and thus error. Removing the space allows the code to be compiled.

Comment: I edited your answer to change `space` to `newline/line break` because there is a difference (and I was looking at the wrong place in your examples here when I thought you meant a plain-old space)

Comment: The compiler is whitespace agnostic...

Comment: I use sublime text 3. Maybe that was the issue? Once I removed the line break it compiled and worked.